# Xcode 8 Your development team, does not support the iCloud capability

Tags: ios, xcode

Good Morning,

I am having trouble with my iPad app this morning, I am trying to test it on a device and all of sudden I get this error message 'Your development team, "My Development Team", does not support the iCloud capability.'

I read somewhere I can just turn on iCloud capabilities by going to Targets -> Capabilities -> Turn iCloud on, the problem is I don't see an iCloud capability.

How can I add iCloud capability so I can run my app.

This is in Xcode 8.3.1

Please Help

Here is a screenshot of my capabilities, i dont have iCloud

[image]

Comment: Please check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222524/icloud-set-up-and-provisioning

Comment: any update? Ur problem is fixed

Comment: have you set the correct bundle identifier????

Comment: @RatneshShukla trying these solutions now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html) Apple document will help you. If you have any questions, add a comment, I'll try to help you.

Also, please be aware that if you are creating application for iOS, you should have paid developer account for using CloudKit. According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SupportedCapabilities/SupportedCapabilities.html) document.

Comment: What if I don't want to use iCloud capabilities?  I dont really feel the need for it, or is this required?

Comment: Have you enabled iCloud in your project? Can you please show us the screenshot? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Art/2_enable_cloudkit_2x.png

Comment: I see. Do you really need all these thing in your current app? I suggest you to switch off all unused ones. Also do you have Apple developer account?

Comment: I do have an Apple developer account and No I do not need all of those capabilities

Comment: I believe it's better to disable them, but it will not help in this particular case. Can you please also show us your info.plst?

Comment: And another questions - how do you get this error? And how do you transfer application to device? Have you added your iPad's ID into list of devices in iTunesConnect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151741/discussion-between-dj-glock-and-user979331).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem two years later.

I think it came up because I started an iCloud testing in my project and didn´turn it off. Today I´m a developer without a paid account. And this probably caused this issue. iCloud capabilities are for paying developers only. And Apple obviously turns this feature off when you don´t want to continue paying. But Apple forgets to turn off a switch which is located in **project.pbxproj**.

You can go to this file by right clicking your project file **myProject.xcodeproj** and choose view package. You can use any text editor to edit this file. At about line 686 it says:

```
SystemCapabilities = {
                        com.apple.iCloud = {
                            enabled = 1;
```

That means **com.apple.iCloud** is **enabled**.

Change 1 to 0 which means **com.apple.iCloud** is **disabled**:

```
SystemCapabilities = {
                        com.apple.iCloud = {
                            enabled = 0;
```

See picture below. This corrected the issue in **myProject.xcodeproj**.

Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: Trying to do this for `Multipath` capability doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Restarting of Xcode solved this error for me.